# Open Webview with custom html containing an image

Tags: android, image, webview

So I have this simple app and what I want to do is, when I hit the button I want to open the WebView and show custom HTML website with my image (for now it will be an icon on the res/drawable folder)

This is what my WebView looks like:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    //image to byte[]
    Bitmap bmBef = null;
    Bitmap bmAft = null;
      BitmapFactory.Options bmo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmo.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;

        String patth = "android.resource://com.mkyong.android/drawable/ic_launcher.png";
        bmBef = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(patth, bmo);
        //byte[] b = bitmapToByteArray(bmBef);





    byte[] imageRaw = bitmapToByteArray(bmBef);
      String image64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageRaw, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + image64 + "\" /></img></body></html>";
    webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");

}

public static byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bm) {
    // Create the buffer with the correct size
    int iBytes = bm.getWidth() * bm.getHeight() * 4;
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(iBytes);

    // Log.e("DBG", buffer.remaining()+""); -- Returns a correct number based on dimensions
    // Copy to buffer and then into byte array
    bm.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    // Log.e("DBG", buffer.remaining()+""); -- Returns 0
    return buffer.array();
}

}
```

But it crashes at this line
        `int iBytes = bm.getWidth() * bm.getHeight() * 4;`
What am I missing? is the path wrong and no image then at that path so I get a nullpointer?
How do I fix the path?
In the future I would want to take a pic with the camera and use it, instead of the icon I use right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say it crashes, what is the error? Have a look in your LogCat output for the source of the problem. In the meantime, this code loads images for me in a WebView:

```
File rootDirectory = mContext.getFilesDir();
String baseUrl = "file://" + rootDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + filePath + File.separator;          

String imageName = <somthing_that_provides_your_fiename>;
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(rootDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + filePath + imageName);
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();

int scale = width * 100 / image.getWidth();

browser.setInitialScale(scale);
browser.loadUrl(baseUrl + imageName);
```

I'm scaling the image based on the width but you may want to check width and height.

Comment: I just found my problem , I had to set permissions in the Manifest in order to be able to see the files.